# try～catchの中のswitch文で、switchの上階層にあるtry～catch文を抜けたい

Tags: php

**現状**

```
try {
  switch ($test) {
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
    case 3:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
    default:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
  }
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
}
```

---

**やりたいこと**
・2の時、try～catchを抜けたい
・試してみたけど、うまくいかないコード

```
try {
  switch () {
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      $hoge = FALSE;
      break 2;
    case 3:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
    default:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
  }
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
}
//ココへ飛ばしたい
```

---

もしくは、下記みたいなことは出来ないでしょうか？

```
try {
  switch () {
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      $hoge = FALSE;
      throw new HogeException('');
    case 3:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
    default:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
  }
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
} catch (HogeException $e) {
  //ここで2だけを捕捉したい
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch`句は記述された順序で評価されます。
`HogeException`が`RuntimeException`を継承していたなら、先にcatch RuntimeExceptionを書くとそちらに捕捉されてしまいます。
そのような場合は記述の順序を変えてみてください。

```
try {
  switch () {
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      $hoge = FALSE;
      throw new HogeException('');
    case 3:
    default:
      throw new RuntimeException('');
  }
} catch (HogeException $e) { // HogeException を先に捕捉する

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

}
```

参考：[例外処理の実装を把握する - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fcoding/articles/php5dev/01/php5dev01b.html)

> catch句は複数設定可能で、スクリプトの上から順に判定されていく。また、ある例外クラスのサブクラスは、継承関係にある親クラスが指定されたcatch句にも捕捉される。
>
> つまり上の例でいえば、発生した例外がTestExceptionであっても、Exceptionクラスを指定したcatch句にも捕捉されるということだ。そのため、catch句の順番をTestExceptionクラスとExceptionクラスとで逆にしてしまうと、例外TestExceptionは先に出てきたExceptionクラスが指定されたcatchブロックに捕捉されてしまい、TestExceptionを指定した2番目のcatchブロックは処理されなくなってしまう。

Answer (score 0):

ほとんどご自分で解答を書かれているように思うのですが、HogeExceptionを定義してやるだけでいいのではないですか?

```
class HogeException extends Exception {}
```

このように限定された用途なら、goto文を使うのも有りだと思います。